# Rank of an Augmented matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Can the rank of **coeffecient matrix** be greater than **augmented matrix**?
Also,what is the condition for an inconsistent set of linear equations?

Answer (score 5):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the span of its columns. The coefficient matrix has fewer columns than the augmented matrix. So, the answer to your first question is no. I don't understand the second one.

Answer (score 5):

For the system $AX=B$ where $A$ is $n×n$ matrix:

1. $Rank(A)=Rank(C)=n$ implies unique solution.
2. $Rank(A)=Rank(C)<n$ implies infinitely many solutions.
3. $Rank(A)<Rank(C)$ implies no solution (inconsistent).

Comment: What is $C$ in the system $AX=B$?

Comment: $C=[A:B]$ is the augmented matrix.